# Python daemon can see database, but complains that tables do not exist

Tags: python, sqlite, python-daemon

I have a vanilla python that connects to a sqlite database.

Everything works fine until I try to run it as a daemon. Here is the code I'm using to do that:

```
def start(self):
  if self.lockfile.is_locked():
    exit_with_code(7, self.pid_file)

  # If we're running in debug, run in the foreground, else daemonise
  if self.options['debug']:
    try:
      self.main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass
    finally:
      self.close_gracefully()
  else:
    context = daemon.DaemonContext(
      files_preserve = [self.logger.socket(), self.lockfile]
    )

    context.signal_map = {
      signal.SIGTERM: self.close_gracefully
    }

    with context: self.main()
```

I can run it in the foreground with `python -m starter -debug` and everything is fine, my app writes into the database, but when I leave the debug flag off I see the following when I try to write:

```
no such table: Frontends
```

I know that the frontends table exists because I've opened the database up. I assume that python is finding the database, because there would be an entirely different error message otherwise.

All my files are owned by vagrant, and `ls -l` shows the following:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 9216 Nov  9 18:09 development.sqlite
```

Anyone got any tips?

**Update**

As requested, here is the code for my db

```
import os
import sqlite3

class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, db_file='/vagrant/my_daemon/db/development.sqlite'):

        self.db = sqlite3.connect(db_file)

        if os.path.exists(db_file):
            print "db exists"
```

And when I run this it prints "db exists". I instantiate the database in starter.py with a call to `Database()`.

Comment: Your assumption is likely to be wrong. Show the code that tries to open the database.

Comment: Which of these two file names is correct?

Comment: @CL the correct filename is development.sqlite, I updated the question

Comment: I think this might be an issue with vagrant/puppet as I find the following in syslog: `Nov  9 20:44:26 puppet-agent[1402]: Did not receive certificate`, and I'm beginning to think my packages have failed to insitall correctly. I'll a brand new VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python daemon closes all open file descriptors (except stdin, stout and stderr) when you daemonise.

I spent ages trying to figure out which files to keep open to prevent my database from being inaccessible, and in the end I found that it's easier to initialise the database inside the daemon context rather than outside. That way I don't need to worry about which files should stay open.

Now everything is working fine.